# Is this silverfish? My apartment very dry

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone please confirm whether insect below is a silverfish?  It looks a bit like the picture at our federal government [pest control page](http://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/pest-control-tips/silverfish-firebrats.html).  It also moves with a wiggling motion, as described  at the Wikipedia [Silverfish page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish).

I sprayed it with alcohol, and it seems to be dead.  I've seen this type of insect about once per month.  I don't know why they gravitate to my apartment, as the dehumidifier it set to maximum (35% relative humidity).

Sorry for the quality of the photo, but my iPhone SE does not have adjustable focus that I'm aware of. I can only tell the phone where the feature of interest lies within the picture.

[image: Shot 1]
[image: Shot 2]
[image: Shot 3]

Comment: Once per month is a healthy house. A biology teacher would tell you that they are pretty harmless human companions, with a cute name, and you probably won't see damage from them. I have them living under the linings of some old windows. I'm mostly bothered to disturb them. once a month is not worrisome.

Comment: Ick....!!!!  I could *never*....

Comment: you probably have a phobia of insects.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can't think of a single insect that I would like to see inside the home.  Even ants, flies, lady bugs, bees, fruit flies.  They're fine outside (heck anything is fine outside), but if I see them inside, 9 floors up from the ground, I would immediately wonder how in they heck they got there.  I would naturally worry about an infestation.  So it's the circumstance that feeds the phobia.  Though I suspect that most people would react similarly.  Perhaps not those who study insects,though.

Comment: The reasons that the photo quality is poor are: it's a 0.1MP image, and you were too close. At 401x373 pixels (for the first image) it's obviously a cropped image (which is fine), since that camera is capable of 4032 x 3024 pixels (12 MP); you've cropped to 1/10th the size. **Backing up a little** will permit you to focus and you can still crop the image. Here is an example iPhone picture of a silverfish: http://sanxbile-blog.tumblr.com/post/44634480254/silverfish-are-cute-lookit-dat-little-eye-also - that was taken at low resolution setting, so you could improve on that.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, Rob!  I will try it the next time I need to photograph something very small.  Hopefully not for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Remi is right that it's a silverfish, and here's some macrophotography of Lepisma Saccharina.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Up close, with the fur, they look almost cute.  (I said almost).

Comment: Yes if you compare that to a fly, I dunno why someone would be ickied about silverfish. flies are way worse. wheat and wool moths are worse. here's a guy that married a silverfish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErBgOTBenIA  forest people can live with tarantulas and snakes, I'm sometimes ickied by centipedes, which are garden animals. silverfish are cute and mysterious, they scratch paper and hide, rodents are far worse.

Comment: You're making me feel guilty about having ended my silverfish.  At least they went out with an alcoholic bang.

Comment: nice pictures, but you hardly answer the question. You should provide support for your answer and not just make a statement. Save for your up close pics, this really is more of a comment. Please consider updating with more info

Answer (score 3):

The pictures are very low quality, but yes I think that is a silverfish.

You dehumidifier might affect your throat but will will likely not have much impact on silverfish. The number one rule is to clean. Also, if you live in an appartment building, silverfish can quite easily invade an appartment from another one. So, it might make it harder to fight against silverfish. If needed there are also traps and pesticides.

Comment: Silverfish are suppose to prefer humidity, so they should be flocking to other people's apartment rather than mind.  Maybe I got the ones that strayed.  I will try harder to clean, but things are quite clean already.  At least, compared to other apartments I've seen.  Thanks!