# What is this insect in Southeast Idaho?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This thing ran out of the wall of my dorm hallway. It had a lot of what look like antennae, and it's very fast.

[image: photo of the insect]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Comment: related post: [Is this silverfish? My apartment very dry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/70013/16866)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a silverfish, order Zygentoma (also known as Thysanura). Likely genus *Lepisma* (family Lepismatidae). Zygentoma are insects, and are the sister taxon to Pterygota (winged insects)

Comment: I should have added that these are harmless.

Comment: Admittedly, that was one of my main concerns

Comment: They're harmless to people, but they feed on stuff like paper. Usually the presence of these creatures (not the insect itself) is considered to be related to hygiene issues.

Comment: @wie5Ooma Very loosely related. Not like cockroaches. Many clean homes have silverfish. And they don't generally cause much damage to anything.